# Always scale prints to 100% and not fit page

Tags: windows-10, pdf, printing, printer

Is there a way in Windows 10 to force any print to scale 100% rather than fit to page?

The long story is we are using an application called Shipstation connect to receive shipping labels that print directly to a thermal printer. However shipstation only supports 4"x6" labels and our logistics partner uses 4x4.

This is fine if you download the pdf and print it from chrome with scale at 100%, prints entirely correctly, however their application must be using a fit to page scaling.

Is it possible to override something like that?

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is with the ShipStation product,
have a look at the article
[ShipStation Print Settings](https://help.shipstation.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025869852-ShipStation-Print-Settings).

It describes the setup option
*Account Settings > Printing > Printing > Document Option*,
where the included options might help in the task.

If however the problem is with the PDF printing side, that entirely depends on the
PDF printing software, and we would need more details.